# When does Lil Hal look like a human?

Tags: homestuck

I was looking over the MSPA Wiki and I noticed that Lil Hal had a human looking sprite that I had never seen before.

[image: Lil Hal Human]

So, from my understanding, unless it had a preface that it isn't canon, what is on the wiki is canonically-backed. When is it that we see this form for him, because I never remember seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lil' Hal's human appearance is taken from the flash [[S] MSPA Reader: Mental Breakdown](http://www.mspaintadventures.com/?s=6&p=009348), when the MSPA Reader realizes the quote from Doc Scratch where he asks Rose to consider him one of her 'human uncles' has a more literal meaning as Lil' Hal is a clone of Dirk*, who in turn is the post-scratch version of Dave's Bro, who is Rose's genetic father. During this sequence, a human version of Lil' Hal appears.

<sub>* Lil' Hal becomes a part of ARquisprite, who is in turn a part of Lil' Cal, along with one half of Gamzee and Caliborn. Doc Scratch is created when Cal is combined with a magic cueball by the A2 Black Queen.</sub>